# How do I convert a python list which is in numbers into letters?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a python program which prints out some lists which are created by other python programs in the format of:
`[0, [], 0, 1, [], 1]`

And I would like to change the 0's and 1's to letters, i.e. in the above input, I want to have
`[x, [], x, y, [], y]` as output

So far my code to do this looks like:

```
for x in search.Search(s, s.run()):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    elif x == 1
        return y
```

I know I'm missing something but I'm not too sure what :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
subst = {0: 'x', 1: 'y'}
return [subst.get(v, v) if v else v for v in search.Search(s, s.run()]
```

By using `return` you exit the loop early.

The `if v else v` helps avoid attempting to use the empty lists as keys (which would raise a TypeError; lists are not hashable and thus not allowed as keys). The alternative strategy would be:

```
from collections import Hashable

subst = {0: 'x', 1: 'y'}
hashable = lambda v: isinstance(v, Hashable)
return [subst.get(v, v) if hashable(v) else v for v in search.Search(s, s.run()]
```

The `subst` map is a little easier to extend; but using a function to map the value (as used in [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989945)) could be more readable to you.

Comment: Nop, this will raise Error.`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
`

Comment: Because the list contains other lists => `[0, [], 0, 1, [], 1]`. You could use `[map.get(v, v) if v else v ...` if the sublists are always empty, but that would look a little strange IMHO.

Comment: @DominicKexel: Indeed! I think in this case the `if` works well enough, otherwise a isinstance is needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your code seems rather complex for what is a simple question :s

Comment: @JakobBowyer: it's one approach. Yours is another. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters not going to lie, I prefer your approach completely, just wondering if it will confuse beginners and people new to python :)

Comment: Don't use `map` as a variable name.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: perhaps. I am not as bothered about using *some* masking variable names; `id` and `map` are two of those. Then again, were supposed to be examplifying best practices, so I'll change that  here.

Answer (score 3):

Return breaks execution, you probably want something like this

```
def switch_letter(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 'x'
    if x == 1:
        return 'y'
    return x

my_letters = [switch_letter(x) for x in search.Search(s, s.run())]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to Martjin's answer. May be you can try this. But it works for python>2.4

```
>>> a=[0, [], 0, 1, [], 1]
>>> s={0:'x',1:'y'}
>>> [x if isinstance(x,list) else s.get(x,'') for x in a]
['x', [], 'x', 'y', [], 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2
     a= [0, [], 0, 1, [], 1]
     b={0:"x",1:"y"}
     result=[b[i] if isinstance(i,int) else [] for i in a]


  2. [i  if isinstance(i,list) else b[i] for i in a ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the built-in function map is less verbose and simpler for a non-python programmer to understand than a list compression.

```
def sust(item):
    if item == 0:
        return "x"
    if item == 1:
        return "y"
    return item
output = map(sust, search.Search(s, s.run()))
```

Answer (score -2):

Generators allow if-else statement inside. In this case your code will looks next.

```
['y' if i else 'x' for i in search.Search(s, s.run()]
```

Comment: did you even checked your output? he wants `[x, [], x, y, [], y]` and your code returns `['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y']`.

Comment: This would substitute `x` for the empty lists as well.